# Telling cabal where the main module is

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a project with this structure:

```
foo.cabal
src/
    Foo/
        Main.hs
```

and part of foo.cabal looks like this:

```
executable foo
  main-is:             Foo/Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:      src
```

Main.hs has the package name `Foo.Main`. When I build it cabal compiles everything but doesn't create an executable because it says there is no main module.

```
Warning: output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT] If I move Main up a level and change foo.cabal to read `main-is: Main.hs` it works. So can I not have a nested module name for Main?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Main` module must be called `Main`, not `Foo.Main` or anything else.  If you want `Foo.Main`, then rename `main` in it to something like `defaultMain`, then make a top level `Main` module that `imports Foo.Main (defaultMain)` and defines `main = defaultMain`, such as:

```
src/
    Foo/
        Main.hs
    Main.hs
foo.cabal
```

Where

```
-- src/Foo/Main.hs
module Foo.Main
    ( defaultMain
    ) where

defaultMain :: IO ()
defaultMain = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

And

```
-- src/Main.hs
module Main where

import Foo.Main (defaultMain)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
```

Alternatively, you could keep it `Foo.Main.main` and just import it qualified.

Comment: [*Every complete Haskell program must define main in module Main in package main.*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-main)

Comment: if the module exports a `main`, you can write just
`module Main where import Foo.Main (main)`
(with or without explicit importing of `main`

Comment: @maxtaldykin That's not been true for GHC since at least the mid-2000s (I was using `-main-is` around 2006), but the documentation has never been corrected. See the `-main-is` _thing_" documentation in [4.12.6. Options affecting linking](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#options-linker) and my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Cabal's `main-is:` specifies only the filename from which to build the module containing the entrypoint (default `Main.main`); it does not allow *changing* that default.

Changing the default is compiler-specific, but if you are using GHC you can do this by passing a compiler command-line option: to your Cabal file `executable` definition add `ghc-options: -main-is Foo`. You may also use a different top-level function as the entry point: `ghc-options: Foo.startup` for example. See [`-main-is <thing>`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.2.1-rc1/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#ghc-flag--main-is%20%E2%9F%A8thing%E2%9F%A9) in the documentation for more details.

If you're using a `package.yaml` (as used by [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack)/Stack/etc.) you may specify for `main:` either:

1. A `.hs` filename, in which case that will be directly used on the `main-is:` line in the generated Cabal file; or
2. A module name or module and exported definition name (e.g., `Foo` or `Foo.startup`) in which case the appropriate `ghc-options: -main-is ...` will be added to the generated Cabal file and `main-is:` will be a filename generated from the module name (e.g. `main-is: Foo.hs`).