# How to run a haskell source file with a custom module name using cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have the below source file and would like to run it directly from terminal but get the following error:

```
<no location info>: error:
    output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated
because there is no Main module.
```

The file:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
build-depends:  base
              , QuickCheck
              , checkers

-}

{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module SkiFree where

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers
import Test.QuickCheck.Classes

data S n a = S (n a) a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor n  => Functor (S n) where
  fmap f (S fx y) = S (f <$> fx) (f y) 

instance Foldable n => Foldable (S n) where
  foldr f ini (S fx y) = foldr f (f y ini) fx


instance Traversable n => Traversable (S n) where
  traverse f (S tx y)= S <$> traverse f tx <*> f y


instance (Functor n
        , Arbitrary (n a)
        , Arbitrary a )
      => Arbitrary (S n a) where
  arbitrary = S <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary

instance (Applicative n
        , Testable (n Property)
        , Eq a
        , Eq (n a)
        , EqProp a)
      =>  EqProp (S n a) where
  (=-=) = eq


main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickBatch $ functor (undefined :: S [] (Int, Float, String))
  quickBatch $ foldable (undefined :: S [] (Int, Float, String, Int, String))
  quickBatch $ traversable (undefined :: S [] (Int, Float, String))
```

I'd like to run this directly from terminal. Without the module name, or if I set it specifically to `Main`, it works just fine.

Is there a way for me to have a custom module name and still run the source file with cabal?

I tried using `main-is` in the `cabal` comment at the top, and also looked at `cabal` options but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Looks like your main module really must be called exactly `Main` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591266/telling-cabal-where-the-main-module-is

Comment: right, thank you for pointing that out. I also found [Every complete Haskell program must define main in module Main in package main...](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-main) in the comments of the SO link you provided.